# Using function as a second parameter in ajax data

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I am trying to call the name of users that are authorized to write news in that particular category and I am using the select2 plugin as there can be more than one writer working on the same news. So when I select a category the option field of the select2 has to show the names of the users.

So far, I have done the following:

```js
$("#news_category").change(function() {
  var CatId = $("#news_category option:selected").attr('value');

  $("#multipleSelect").select2({
    ajax: {
      url: "/process/categoryUsers.php",
      type: "post",
      dataType: 'json',
      delay: 250,
      data: {
        id: CatId
      }, function(params) {
        return {
          searchTerm: params.text
        };
      }
      },
      processResults: function(response) {
        console.log(response)
        return {
          results: response
        };
      },
      cache: true
    }
  });
```

In the log, I am seeing the data that I expect to see but that is not in the option of select2 plugin. I feel like I am doing something wrong in the `data: ....` I am fetching the lists of users with the CatId that I am passing the id as the first parameter and also a function as a second that gives the lists of users when I click to the search of the select2 plugin

I expect to get the lists of the same users that are in the console.

**Note:** I am fetching data that is in the Unicode character

Update: `#news_category` is another select field which is not using the select2 plugin so, on change event, I am fetching the category id that comes in the selected option which I have assigned to CatId to fetch users. Suppose, I got 1 in the variable CatId, I am passing that CatId as a parameter to fetch users who are allowed to write news in the category id 1. Like I said I am getting expected value in the console log I just want to show them in the dropdown.

Comment: Your syntax against `data` is incorrect. What it's saying at the moment is this is being passed as a json `{id: CatId }` which is fine but then you've got that function which is being passed as what? It won't work

Comment: What is `params`, and where is it defined. Presumably you can fix the syntax by just doing: `data: { id: CatId, searchTerm: params.text }`

Comment: @JamesS I got the idea of that on this [link](https://makitweb.com/loading-data-remotely-in-select2-with-ajax/). If I have understood correctly, that works for a search field.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I tried your code but it says params is not defined.

Comment: In which case that's the first issue to solve. What are you expecting `params` to be?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I expect the params to be id and text that I am getting in the console log.

Comment: Where? Please edit the code to show that

Comment: Regarding params. I looked at that link but `params` is not defined anywhere?

Comment: @JamesS params.term can be used to get the value of entered data but as you can see the example given in the [link](https://makitweb.com/loading-data-remotely-in-select2-with-ajax/#demo) is showing some values just after clicking on the select2 plugin.

Comment: Hi Alisha, I have updated my answer. It seems you are using jquery to get the id of the dropdown and then using params or whatever to get the other. Instead you could do what I have done in the edit of my answer. That should return the text of the dropdown.

Answer (score 0):

Like I said in my comment, I feel like you are doing something wrong in `data`. To pass the controller a return from a function I would do this.

```
function Getparam (params) {
    return {
      searchTerm: params.text 
    };
```

}

and then in the data do:

```
`data: {id: CatId, param: Getparam(params)}`
```

This passes both id and whatever param is in json

EDIT: It looks like you just want to return the text of the dropdown yeah?

You could just do this instead of using whatever params is:

```
var ddtext = $("#news_category option:selected").text();
```

and then in `data` have `data: {id: CatId, text: ddtext}`

EDIT 2: 
To set another dropdown's values you could use the markup below.

```
        //Create a markup for a select
        var markup = "<option Value='0'>Select option</option>";

        //Populate the markup
        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            markup += "<option Value=" + result[i].Value + ">" + result[i].Text + "</option>";
        }

        //Populate dropdown with value
        $("#//DROPDOWNLIST ID").html(markup).show();
```

NOTE: This is html markup. This woudl be situated in the `success` or in your case `processResults` of your ajax call and would populate the dropdown with data passed back in the `processResults` response

Comment: Passing `params` as an argument to a function to get a single property from that object seems pretty redundant.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan I seen that, this was just regarding calling a function like the code shown in the question. Other than that I would do the example shown in your comment. Simply passing `params.text` as in the json

Comment: @JamesS Yes, you got that. I want to display the name in the dropdown also I want to set the value coming in the key id in the value attr.

Comment: @JamesS I have updated my question. Can you please have a look.

Comment: @AlishaLamichhane You want to populate one dropdown based off the selected value in another?